# Jscript not printing to element

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea why this isn't working. I mean as far as I know It should print my array in alphabetical order to the div "output"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Lexicographic ordering </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var words = [];
        var input = prompt("Please enter a word or type end to stop prompts");
    while (input != 'end') {
        words.push(input);
        input = prompt("Please enter a word or type end to stop prompts");
    }
    words.sort();
    getElementById('#output').innerHTML= words.join();
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <header>Lexicographic Ordering </header>
    <hr>
 <div class ="page-wrapper">
     h1> Lexicographic Ordering </h1>
    <div id="output"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is happening instead? Try `getElementById('output').innerHTML=words.join();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also try to move the `<script>` block at the end, just before closing of the `</body>`. Anywhere after the `<div id="output"></div>`.

JavaScript on some browsers fails when they have to reference some elements which has not been parsed by their HTML parser when the script is executing or trying to reference them.

Also, you don't use `#` with `getElementById(...);`. `#` is used with Jquery. This is pure JavaScript. Make it `getElementById('output').whatever...;`

### Edit:

Another option suggested by Patrick Evans is to move the JavaScript Code in an `onload()` event handler method to execute the code. This ensures that the HTML is fully loaded in the DOM before we try to manipulate it.

Comment: instead of moving it to the end you should keep it in the head and use the `onload` event to make sure the DOM is ready to be manipulated.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thanks for your valuable input. I have edited my answer to include your suggestion for `onload()` and one from my side for the `document.ready()`. Thanks again!

Comment: by document.ready do you mean jQuery's `.ready` function, as `document` doesnt have a method named `ready` :)

Comment: you're right! I have removed it. May be we're so engrossed in using it that sometimes we ignore the fact that Jquery is just a JavaScript framework ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

There are two small bugs in your code, and they're both in this line:

```
getElementById('#output').innerHTML= words.join();
```

`getElementById` is not a part of the `window`, it's a part of the `document` object, so you must reference it properly. Also, that method takes an ID, not a selector, so you don't need the # in front of it.

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML= words.join();
```

That should do what you want! Alternatively, since I notice you have jQuery included, you could do `$('#output').innerHTML = ...` to achieve the same effects.

Comment: I finally got it to work but for some reason I had to place the 

 `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML= words.join();`


after the div. Like in the footer. It's ugly but it will work

Comment: @CoreyBuchillon, you did the right thing. Check my answer for clarification on this.